# DocuSign: start signing process without full list of recipients

Tags: docusignapi

Use case:
There are 3 people who need to sign the document in total. Only 2 of them are known at the moment. Another missing recipient will be decided later on.

Currently I after browsing docusign api I see 3 possibilities for implementing the solution:

1). Start signing process by providing emails for 3 recipients: 2 valid ones and one fake email. Later on this fake email will be replaced by a real person's email, when such a person will be known. This can be done quite easily using "Add Recipients to an Envelope" and "Delete Recipients from an Envelope" endpoints, as described in REST api guide. However, this would mean, that for all such cases we will have to provide the same "fake" email, and I was wondering whether this is considered as a service abuse.

2). Create envelope in a draft state ("create") with 2 participants. Later on add 3rd recipient to it (by invoking mentioned above endpoint), and finally send it. The drawback here is that 2 persons will be waiting for the 3rd to start signing process - so this solution is less than optimal for our application.

3). Send envelope with only 2 recipients, and add 3rd one later. This has a risk that initial 2 persons will sign the envelope, and it will be considered complete - when in fact 3 persons are needed for this action. So this solution is probably incorrect.

If there are other/better ways to achieve same results, please let me know.

Comment: I agree 3 should be taken off the list of consideration. For option 1 i view it as a "placeholder signer" and certainly would meet your requirements. DocuSign has the notion of 'address recipients' role where a person later in the workflow provides the signers information - option 1 is similar to that concept but specific to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From DocuSign website: "Address recipients: ...This recipient can add name and email information for recipients that appear after the recipient in workflow order. The reviewer must fill out the missing information for the recipients _before_ sending the envelope" -> so this applies to envelopes in "created" state only (solution 2), if I get this correctly.

Comment: @LuisScott - please re-do your comment as an answer. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

I agree 3 should be taken off the list of consideration. For option 1 i view it as a "placeholder signer" and certainly would meet your requirements. DocuSign has the notion of 'address recipients' role where a person later in the workflow provides the signers information - option 1 is similar to that concept but specific to your use case.